# Redis Multinode + SAP Cloud

Tags: redis, cloud, node-redis, redis-sentinel

I have deployed my application on **SAP Cloud Foundary** which creates connection with **Redis Multinode** instance running on the cloud.
The application can push and fetch data from Redis successfully.
Now I want to check high availability of Redis Nodes by crashing nodes of redis one by one (**cloud has the instance of Redis with 3 nodes, 1 being master and other 2 as its slave**).
I have been trying to crash anyone of the nodes by using **redis-cli, ssh connection** but could not get success in that.
Can anyone please help me to know how to crash any single node of **Redis cluster** in **SAP cloud** environment?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: I don't think you need so much bold text in your question.